# Capybara waiting for page load when jquery always active

Tags: ruby, ajax, selenium, capybara

I am writing e2e test for an off the shelf app that used Google Web Toolkit(GWT). Sometimes even when the element on the page exists, clicking on it doesn't work because even though the page has loaded, some components of it haven't loaded completely. Adding a sleep(allow page to load) fixes it. I am not waiting for the actual element as it already exists!! I can't wait for all ajax to finish as `jquery.active` always returns `1` on this app.

What's the best way to handle such waits?

Comment: Assuming the components being loaded have at least some effect on the page, adding classes, data attributes, etc then you can wait for those changes to be made.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. There are too many components on the page and waiting for each of them seems like a lot of effort. I don't even need to interact with those components in first place. It's just how this app is. I am looking for a blanket wait solution in this case if there is any. Or may me something that allows me to check whether all capybara interactions have taken effect and if not, retry them.